# how to print line space below the barcode and text using zpl programming bar code

Tags: php, zpl, barcode-printing, zpl-ii

im using Zebra GK420d Printer. i need to print extra line space below the barcode and text. here my zpl code is like this

```
$barcode_ZPL_code ="^XA4
^FWR
^FO 550,450^A0,20,30^FH^FDCHEDDI_20JAGAN_20AIRPORT_20GUYANA_20OWN_20CLEARING^FS
^FO 400,450^AD^BY2
^BC,100,Y,N,N
^MD1
^FO 350,450^A0,20,30^FH^FDDATE_3A14-10-2014^FS
^FO 300,450^A0,20,40^FH^FDLTX106970_2D1_281_29_2D_UGAC^FS
^XZ";
```

i am unable to get the space between barcode and date field. Please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your ZPL code isn't compiling correctly because some elements are missing.  The printer is trying to render it anyway, but the ^FO is not being honored because the printer is expecting an ^FD...^FS that is missing.

This might be what you are trying to do:

> ^XA4
>   ^FWR
>   ^FO 550,450^A0,20,30^FH^FDCHEDDI_20JAGAN_20AIRPORT_20GUYANA_20OWN_20CLEARING^FS
>   ^FO 400,450^AD^BY2
>   ^BC,100,Y,N,N
>   **^FDyour barcode info goes here^FS**
>   ^MD1
>   ^FO **300**,450^A0,20,30^FH^FDDATE_3A14-10-2014^FS
>   ^FO **275**,450^A0,20,40^FH^FDLTX106970_2D1_281_29_2D_UGAC^FS
>   ^XZ